# How to convert string ( Thu Oct 3 18:45:10 2019) to time_t format in cpp?

Tags: c++

Stored that time format in some other file. And retrieve this as string. How to change this to time format again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strptime` to parse the time, and then `mktime` to convert it to a time_t

```
const char *time_details = "Thu Oct 3 18:45:10 2019";
struct tm tm;

// %a or %A
// The weekday name according to the current locale, in abbreviated form or the full name.
// %b or %B or %h
// The month name according to the current locale, in abbreviated form or the full name.


// the field descriptors must match the string format you are providing. 
strptime(time_details, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", &tm);
time_t t = mktime(&tm);
```

You can find the detailed usage of input field descriptors at [strptime(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime)

Comment: I tried that. But won't work

Comment: What is meant by 'wont work'?  Any error or output?  Please share

Comment: my code :  struct tm tim ;

    char *current_time;
    time_t tm = time(NULL);
    current_time = strtok(ctime(&tm), "\n");
    cout << "before" << tm <<endl;
    cout << "current_time" << current_time <<endl;

    char *s = strptime(current_time, "%a %d %b %H:%M:%S %Y", &tim);
    time_t t = mktime(&tim);

    cout << "time_t : " << t <<endl;      output: before1570172264
current_timeFri Oct  4 12:27:44 2019
time_t : 11829597336

Comment: output gets varied for the same input

Comment: time(NULL) is returning current time. Your current time is changing. So, output will change too.